# delete a space after a period javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, palindrome

I am trying to write a funciton in Javascript that will delete all the spaces and punctuation in the sentence, and then check if it's a palindrome. I've gotten most of it to work, however it won't delete the space after the period in canal. How can I do this?

```
function palindrome(str) {

     str = str.toLowerCase();
     str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
     str = str.replace(/,/g , "");
     str = str.split('.').join(' ');

    document.write(str);

    if(str.split("").reverse().join("") === str) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false; 
    }
}

palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama");
```

Comment: move the `str = str.split('.').join(' ');` line before `str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');`. You are replacing all the spaces and then joining them again using `str = str.split('.').join(' ');`

Answer (score 1):

I would use one replace for spaces, commas, and periods

```js
function palindrome(str) {

     str = str.toLowerCase();
     str = str.replace(/[\s,\.]+/g, '');
    document.write(str);

    if(str.split("").reverse().join("") === str) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false; 
    }
}

console.log(palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"));
```

Comment: i just used the same code, I'm not saying everything is optimal but the `replace` is what he needs to make the code work

Comment: You don't need to escape the `.` inside the `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this way:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    str = str.match(/[a-z]+/gi).join("").toLowerCase();
    document.body.innerHTML = str;
    return(str.split("").reverse().join("") === str);
}

palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama");
```

[Live here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jpajtkza/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this with a regx but you could just

```
yourString.split(". ").join("");
```